# unable to resolve a promise in Nodejs Express

Tags: javascript

I have a written as the following:-

```
const verifiedTokenPromise = token=> new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
  jwt.verify(token,publicCertFile,(err, payload)=>{
    if(err){
      reject(err);
    }else{
      resolve(payload);
    }
  });
});
```

Then I tried to reolve the promise by using a exports function;

```
exports.verifyUserRequest = (token)=>{
  if(!token){
    return false;
  }else{
    async function tokenResolver(token){
      try{
        var payload = await verifiedTokenPromise(token);
        console.log((payload));
        return true;
      }catch(e){
        return false;
      }
    }
    var demo3 = tokenResolver(token);
    return demo3;
  }

}
```

When I am returning the promise, this is coming as undefined.

```
exports.isTokenValid = (req, res)=>{
    if(!req.headers['x-api-key']){
        res.status(422).json('No token provided');
    }else{
        confirmation = JWTCertifier.verifyUserRequest(req.headers['x-api-key']);
        console.log("sdjfnsjdnfjsdf"+ " "+confirmation);
        if(confirmation == true){
            res.status(200).json('Valid token');
        }else{
            res.status(401).json('Invalid token');
        }
    }
}
```

Here confirmation is coming as undefined

Comment: `confirmation` should be an unresolved promise as far as I can see. I've no idea how you get `undefined` from it.

Comment: verifyUserRequest is a library function to check for validating user Tokens. IsTokenValid is a Express Controller which calls the library function.

Comment: Ok, I am getting an unresolved Promise Object in confirmation. How to resolve that?

Comment: `demo3` is a promise (and needs to be, since `verify` is an asynchronous function). You need to wait for it. You cannot make it fulfill immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
exports.isTokenValid = async (req, res)=>{
    if(!req.headers['x-api-key']){
        res.status(422).json('No token provided');
    }else{
        confirmation = await JWTCertifier.verifyUserRequest(req.headers['x-api-key']);
        console.log("sdjfnsjdnfjsdf"+ " "+confirmation);
        if(confirmation == true){
            res.status(200).json('Valid token');
        }else{
            res.status(401).json('Invalid token');
        }
    }
}
```

Just use `await JWTCertifier.verifyUserRequest(req.headers['x-api-key']);` instead of `JWTCertifier.verifyUserRequest(req.headers['x-api-key']);`. This is returning `promise`

Answer (score 0):

`tokenResolver` is an `async` function, and `async` functions always returns a `Promise`, so you have to wait for that promise to resolve.